# Reference on Random Variables and Common Operators

Tags: probability-distributions

I have statistical variables whose values are real and follow gamma distributions.
However, the distributions of each of those variables have a different mean and shape parameter.

I want to know what would be the distribution of a weighted mean of those variables.

I would as well need to know what would happen if the considered variables follow an other kind of distributions or if we I apply other operators (log, exp...)

Thereof, could someone suggest a reference book on this topic ?
I had a look at the "Hand-book on Statistical Distributions" by C. Walck and though it is quite useful for their descriptions, it did not really help me there.

Comment: My [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88363/probability-distribution-and-their-related-distributions/88367#88367) contains a page with many of the common random variables and how they are related via various transformations.  I'm not sure that's exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Robert B. Ash](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/)'s online [Lectures on Statistics](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Stat.html) to be a well written overview of statistical techniques. In particular his [first lecture](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf) (pdf) on transformations of random variables.